# What's wrong with Guido's implementation of Super in python?

Tags: python, oop, super

[Cooperative methods and super](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#cooperation)

**This is an example pure python implementation of built in `super` by Guido for illustration purposes. I need some clarification on implementation of class `Super` below**

In the code below invocation `someobj.__mro__` won't work. See my comment against the line.
With built in `super` simply an error is thrown.

`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Question:

My question is what was the intent of having that line in the first place?

So if the passed in object is not an instance of the passed in class then start using the object's mro...why??

```
class Super(object):
        def __init__(self, type, obj=None):
            self.__type__ = type
            self.__obj__ = obj
        def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
            if self.__obj__ is None and obj is not None:
                return Super(self.__type__, obj)
            else:
                return self
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            if isinstance(self.__obj__, self.__type__):
                starttype = self.__obj__.__class__
            else:
                starttype = self.__obj__   ## This line does not work
            mro = iter(starttype.__mro__)
            for cls in mro:
                if cls is self.__type__:
                    break
            # Note: mro is an iterator, so the second loop
            # picks up where the first one left off!
            for cls in mro:
                if attr in cls.__dict__:
                    x = cls.__dict__[attr]
                    if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
                        x = x.__get__(self.__obj__)
                    return x
            raise AttributeError, attr

class A(object):
        def m(self):
            '''  m in A'''
            return "A"

class B(A):
        def m(self):
            '''  m in B'''
            return "B" + Super(B, self).m()

class C(A):
        def m(self):
            ''' m in C '''
            return "C" + Super(C, self).m()

class D(C):
        def m(self):
            ''' m in D'''
            return "D" + Super(B, self).m()

print D().m() # "DCBA"
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./supertest.py", line 73, in <module>
    print D().m() # "DCBA"
  File "./supertest.py", line 71, in m
    return "D" + Super(B, self).m()
  File "./supertest.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    mro = iter(starttype.__mro__)
AttributeError: 'D' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

<strike>The object you passed as `obj` was an old-style object (instance of an old-style class). These all have the type `classobj` and are not subclasses of `object` and are not of type `type` (or a subclass of `type`).</strike>

Although the struck out text is correct in its description of old-style objects, having seen the full code and exception, this is not the issue causing that exception. The exception above is built-in `super` catching the mistake identified below: `D` is not a subclass of `B`, so `super` is telling you it can't do anything with that pair of inputs.

> My question is what was the intent of having that line in the first place?

The issue triggering your traceback (the full traceback, not the first error, dealt with above) is that `D` is not a subclass of `B`.

In this code:

```
if isinstance(self.__obj__, self.__type__):
    starttype = self.__obj__.__class__
else:
    starttype = self.__obj__   ## This line does not work
mro = iter(starttype.__mro__)
```

The assumption is that if `__obj__` is not an instance of `__type__`, then `__obj__` is a type itself, and it has an mro. There is no handler for the case that you supply a type which is not a baseclass (or the class) of the `__obj__`, because there is nothing that `super` (or `Super`) can sensibly do with it.

The only design flaw here is that the constructor should probably catch this case, and generate an appropriate exception.

Finally, I note that the code you have posted is not the same as the code in document to which you link. Guido's code does not in fact trigger this issue.

Comment: @abc Until you post the full stacktrace, I cannot comment on your code. All you say is that a line "does not work".

Comment: Ok I posted the stacktrace now. But you really need to take a closer look at what I am asking. Don't get to focussed  on the bug in the code please.

Comment: @abc There is no bug in the `Super` code. The bug is in your use of it, as I explain above.

Comment: I see now. Builtin `super` can be called as such : `super(type, type2)` which requires that `type2` is a subclass of `type`. In the `Super` implementation when called as such `Super(type, type2)` `isinstance(type2, type)` will fail leading to `__mro__` of `type2` being evaluated. So basically `Super` is trying to have feature parity with builtin `super`.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is a bug in the `Super` code above. My usage of it (as shown above) causes it to blow up. But builtin `super`  gives a more polished error message. You also hinted at it in your description above.

Comment: @abc That's a matter of opinion. I'd call it a suboptimal design rather than a bug: both work correctly with input which respects the contract, and both blow up with the same incorrect input, rather than doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see now. Builtin `super` can be called as such : `super(type, type2)` which requires that type2 is a subclass of type. In the `Super` implementation when called as such `Super(type, type2)` `isinstance(type2, type)` will fail leading to **mro** of type2 being evaluated. So basically Super is trying to have feature parity with builtin